# Log4net: Add line with characters after logmessage

Tags: configuration, log4net

I like a breakline after each logmessage in my file.

At this moment I set a threadcontext-property and use it in the patternLayout.

C#:

```
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["break"] = "###########################################";
```

log4net.config:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern"  value="%date - %property{Guid} [%level] %newline  %message %newline %newline %property{break} %newline" />
</layout>
```

Is it possible to define this in the config-file of log4net?
It doesn't have to be the same character. I just need a visible way to see the messages has ended and a new one starts since the messages itself are pretty big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not add it to your ConversionPattern:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern"  value="%date - %property{Guid} [%level] %newline  %message %newline %newline %property{break} %newline ########################################### %newline " />
</layout>
```

Comment: Hmmm. That's an idea. :-) Don't know why I didn't think of that... Thanks.